# Angular directive dom build

Tags: angularjs

When I open my page, messages output from in to out like a bubble event. Message 2, Message 1. But I need output Message 1, Message 2 like a tunnel event. Why did it happen so?

```
<div by-global-size="width:100%;height:5%;">
<div by-parent-size="width:50%;height:30%;">
</div>
</div>

.directive("byGlobalSize", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            alert("Message 1");
        },
        restrict: "A",
        scope: true
    }
})
.directive("byParentSize", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
           alert("Message 2");
        },
        restrict: "A",
        scope:true
    }
});
```

I will not have two directives, this is just an example.

```
<div by-global-size="width:100%;height:5%;">
<div by-parent-size="width:50%;height:30%;">
<div by-parentChild-size="width:100%;height:5%;">
<div by-parentChildLittle-size="width:50%;height:30%;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

One more HTML example. From parent to child, I need build dom tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following example at plunker. The compile function takes two functions, 
pre compile and post compile.

```
directive('myDirective', function myDirective($log){
  var directive = { 
    retstrict : 'A',
    compile : function compile(){
      return {
          pre : function(scope, iElem, iAttr){
                //Your code goes here
          },
          post : function(scope, iElem, iAttr){
                // in essence the link function
          }
       }
     }

  };
  return directive;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/zEk0icn4KaQFtX0WHonj?p=preview

The link function is in essence the post compile function. What you need is the pre-compile method with works from outter to inner.

Comment: Build result, inner -> outter, but i need outter -> inner. How inner will know about size parent if he does not initliazed first?...

Comment: Sorry, i think it's work be pre... yes. i night will trying in project if it's works i told you, thanks. I answer very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If there is somehow a hierarchy, you should use the `require` keyword in your directive :

```
.directive("byParentSize", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
           alert("Message 2");
        },
        restrict: "A",
        scope:true,
        require:'^byGlobalSize',
    }
});
```

Comment: I need it for all directives. Not only for this two directives... It's just example.